# How to proper setup for xamarin development as c# developper?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-sdk-tools, mobile-development

I'm facing a serious issue and don't know how to fix it, i'm a c# developper but i'm new to mobile development using xamarin in visual studio, i've dowloaded the xamarin with all the installation package, then i went throught all the step to creating a xamarin form, i've downloaded all the android sdk down to Nougat version (7)
But when to trying to run the app, it shows errors. I looked all over the internet but i got no correct answer. So if someone know a solution to this problem, please help me with this.

[See the picture of the errors list window after i click on the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRi6v.jpg)

Please help me !!!!!!!

---------------------------------This part down is the message shown in the output window----------------------------------------

```
1>------ Début de la génération : Projet : App2, Configuration : Debug Any CPU ------
Detecting installed packages
Detecting installed packages...
Creating C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
Creating C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
Copying platform assemblies...
Copying platform assemblies...
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\Mono.Android.Export.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v4.4\OpenTK-1.0.dll
Copying file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v9.0\Mono.Android.dll
Copying platform assemblies...
Creating: C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\AndroidManifest.xml
Creating: C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\unsigned.apk
Executing: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe package -f -0 .dll -0 .mdb -M "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\AndroidManifest.xml" -I "C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-28\android.jar" -F "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\unsigned.apk" -k "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\r"
Aapt
C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\28.0.3\aapt.exe exited with value: 0
Aapt
Creating: C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\unaligned.jar
Executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\jarsigner.EXE -keystore "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore" -storepass android -keypass android -digestalg SHA1 -sigalg md5withRSA -signedjar "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\unaligned.jar" "C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1\unsigned.apk" androiddebugkey
jarsigner
jarsigner error: java.lang.RuntimeException: keystore load: C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore (Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable)
C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\jarsigner.EXE exited with value: 1
jarsigner
Removing temporary directory: C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Temp\rx4qphcd.nr1
Creating C:\Users\Aboubacar Traoré\AppData\Local\Xamarin.Android\Cache\Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_28.apk
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\11\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\16\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\30\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\28\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\12\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\35\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\29\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\18\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
1>C:\Users\Aboubacar Traor├®\source\repos\App2\App2\obj\Debug\90\lp\31\jl\res : error APT0000: failed to open directory: Le fichier sp├®cifi├® est introuvable. (2).
========== Génération : 0 a réussi, 1 a échoué, 0 mis à jour, 0 a été ignoré ==========
========== Déploiement : 0 a réussi, 0 a échoué, 0 a été ignoré ==========
```

Comment: "failed to open directory" - try creating a folder "c:\projects" or similar to keep your source code in, it sounds like there may be some sort of issue with the naming of your home folder that VS doesn't like

Comment: Thank your for your answer but i don't know anything about mobile development. What folder do you mean ?

Comment: I think the xaml file is ok and the mainActivity is also ok i don't what code to put in folders

Comment: You could check the path of the directory. And test with removing the none english character to rebuild and debug the application on the device.

Comment: Thank your so much !!! I relocated the projet into another directory and it did work just fine... Thank you

Comment: Ofcourse no problem

Comment: Can you upvote my question to to make it Zero 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check the path of the directory. And test with removing the none english character to rebuild and debug the application on the device.